# listview Search: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence)'

Tags: android, android-search

I already read all the questions that has a same error like in my code,
I don't know whats wrong, Please help me

FragmentSearch.java

```
adapter = new FunDapter<>(SearchFragment.this.getActivity(), itemList, R.layout.search_row, dic);
    lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvSearch);
    searcher = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.Search);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    searcher.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.junamay.matchdeals.Fragments.SearchFragment$5.onQueryTextChange(SearchFragment.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1209)
                                                                                  at android.widget.SearchView.access$2000(SearchView.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1689)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8175)
```

Thank you in ADVANCE

Comment: your `FunDapter` returns null from `getFilter()` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: Show how you declare adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should define a filter for your adapter depending of the type of your objects
See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html)